# Change day after hour js html

Tags: javascript, html, days

i have a code:

```js
var dayNames = new Array("wednesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday",
  "wednesday", "thursday", "friday");
var now = new Date();
document.write("Buy nowe, you geti it on " + dayNames[now.getDay()]);
```

```html
<a id="orderBy"></a>
```

I would like to change a day for next after 2pm. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this - I am assuming any day after Friday at 14:00 and before Wednesday at 14:00 means Wednesday delivery

```js
const dayNames = ["wednesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"];
let now = new Date();
if (now.getHours() >= 14) now.setDate(now.getDate()+1)
document.write("Buy nowe, you geti it on " + dayNames[now.getDay()]);
```

```html
<a id="orderBy"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the time to be 14 hours from now. So if it's 2pm or after, it'll be considered 12:00am the next day and after.

```
let shippingTime = new Date();
shippingTime.setHours(shippingTime.getHours() + 14);

document.write("Buy now, you get it on " + dayNames[shippingTime.getDay()]);

<a id="orderBy"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();
if (now.getHours() >= 14){
    day += 1;
}

document.write("Buy nowe, you geti it on " + dayNames[day]);
```

Comment: This will fail on all Saturdays when day will be greater than the length of the array